# integral2 returns 0 when it shouldn't

Tags: matlab, integral

I am having the following issue. I am trying to integrate a pdf function of bivariate normal over the entire support. However, Matlab returns 0 for d, which shouldn't be the case. What is wrong with my approach?

The code is below:

```
mu1=100;
mu2=500;
sigma1=1;
sigma2=2;
rho=0.5;
var1=sigma1^2;
var2=sigma2^2;

pdf = @(x,y) (1/(2*pi*sigma1*sigma2*sqrt(1-rho^2))).*exp((-1/(2*(1-rho^2)))*(((x-mu1).^2/var1)+((y-mu2).^2/var2)-((2*rho*(x-mu1).*(y-mu2))/(sigma1*sigma2))));

d = integral2(pdf,-Inf,Inf,-Inf,Inf)
```

Comment: Please attach original integral (image or formula)

Comment: If the formula is correct I could imagine that your Gaussian bump of width 1 isn't picked up by the integrator. You are telling it to integrate from infinity to infinity, and you have a single bump hidden at `[100, 500]`. Exponentials cut off very fast away from the peak, so I wouldn't be too surprised if ran into a problem here. I have no idea how `integral2` works, this is just general musing.

Comment: `pdf(42,23)` (or any other number) is always 0. Something is wrong with your formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Andras Deak commented, the "exponentials cut off very fast away from the peak".
As a matter of fact, you can visualize it:

```
mu1=100;
mu2=500;
sigma1=1;
sigma2=2;
rho=0.5;
var1=sigma1^2;
var2=sigma2^2;

pdf = @(x,y) (1/(2*pi*sigma1*sigma2*sqrt(1-rho^2))).*exp((-1/(2*(1-rho^2)))*(((x-mu1).^2/var1)+((y-mu2).^2/var2)-((2*rho*(x-mu1).*(y-mu2))/(sigma1*sigma2))));
figure
fsurf(pdf,[90 110 490 510])
figure
fsurf(pdf,[0 200 400 600])
```

In the first figure, the limits are close to the means you provided. You can see the shape of the bivariate normal:
[image]

If you extend the limits, you will see what it looks like a discontinuity:
[image]

The built-in integral functions try to evaluate the integrals, but if your limits are `-inf` and `inf`, your function is zero almost everywhere, with a discontinuity close to the means.

[To treat singularities](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/singularity-on-interior-of-integration-domain.html), you should break your domain, as suggested by MATLAB. Since the function is zero almost everywhere, you can integrate only around the means:

```
d = integral2(pdf,90,110,490,510)

> d =
> 
>     1.0000
```

You can also write it as a function of your variables. The [empirical rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) states that 99.7% of your data is within 3 standard deviations from the means, so:

```
d = integral2(pdf,mu1-3*sigma1,mu1+3*sigma1,mu2-3*sigma2,mu2+3*sigma2)

> d =
> 
>     0.9948
```

which will get you a pretty good result.
We can elaborate more. In the wikipedia page of the empirical rule, the expression

```
erf(x/sqrt(2))
```

will give the "Expected fraction of population inside range `mu+-x*sigma`". For the short precision shown as standard in MATLAB, if you choose, say x=5, you will get:

```
x = 5;
erf(x/sqrt(2))

> ans =
> 
>     1.0000
```

Pretty much every data is contained within 5 standard deviations. So, you may neglect the domain outside this range in the double integration to avoid the (almost) singularity.

```
d = integral2(pdf,mu1-x*sigma1,mu1+x*sigma1,mu2-x*sigma2,mu2+x*sigma2)

> d =
> 
>     1.0000
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it helps a lot!